# Function to check elements in an array in scala

Tags: scala, function

```
def f(c: String) = {
  val array = ("google.com|yahoo.com|gmail.com|mail.com").split("\\|")
  for (i <- array) {
    if (c.contains(i)) {
      println("comparing " + c + " with " + i)
      i
    }
  }
  "N/A"
}
```

My intention for the above function is that, it will return `N/A` if `c` does not contain any of the elements of the array. And, if it does, it will return the element in the array. So if `c="www.google.com/1234"` , ideally the function would return `google.com` and if `c="bloomberg.com/example"`, the function will return `N/A`.

But when I do `println(f("www.google.com/1234"))` I get `N/A`.
Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: The `for()` statement goes through the entire `array`. After it's finished the program moves to the next line: `"N/A"` Since that's the last line of the method, that's what the method returns, no matter what happens in the `for()`..

Answer (score 2):

Your function always returns `N/A`, because it's the last value in its definition. To leave a value in the end like this means in Scala the same as writing `return "N/A"`. But even without `N/A` in the end, your function wouldn't return what you want, because:

1. the last statement would be `for { ... }` which is of type `Unit`
2. your function is side-effecting, by calling `println`, it's not the same as returning a value

Let's write first a function that tries to find a match:

```
def findMatch(c: String): Option[String] = {
  val array = "google.com|yahoo.com|gmail.com|mail.com".split('|')
  array.find(c.contains)
}
```

Notice that the return type is `Option[String]` which comes from the call to the [`find` method](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#find(p:A=%3EBoolean):Option[A]). Now you can use it to print the result if it's there or `N/A` otherwise:

```
def f(c: String): Unit = {
  println(findMatch(c).getOrElse("N/A"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While laughedelics solution looks fine, another one, on your track, is possible too:

```
def f (c: String) : List[String] = {
  val array = ("google.com|yahoo.com|gmail.com|mail.com").split("\\|")
  val list = (for (i <- array 
    if (c.contains(i))) yield {
      println("comparing " + c + " with " + i)
      i
    }).toList
  if (list.isEmpty) List ("N/A") else list
}
```

It prints while iterating and either returns a list of matches, or a List with the String "N/A", which should, in practice, in most cases result in a List of exactly one String, not less or more, but depending on the input, more than one match is possible.

```
scala> f ("www.google.com/1234")
comparing www.google.com/1234 with google.com
res61: List[String] = List(google.com)

scala> f ("www.göögle.com/1234")
res62: List[String] = List(N/A)

scala> f ("www.google.com/1234?param:subject='mail.com'")
comparing www.google.com/1234?param:subject='mail.com' with google.com
comparing www.google.com/1234?param:subject='mail.com' with mail.com
res63: List[String] = List(google.com, mail.com)
```

The main difference to your approach is the use of a yield, to return something from the for-construct.